# Polygon based geofencing in android

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am trying to achieve a polygon based geofencing in my application and just trying to avoid adding up any new libraries. I am not using any maps also in the app. So far, I have found out [Stefan Bangel's tutorial](http://stefanbangels.blogspot.in/2013/10/geo-fencing-sample-code.html)  to findout whether a point is inside a polygon or not.Inside the checkInside(), I am checking wheather it's inside the polygon or not.  But, I have no idea how to manupulate geofencing actions based on that as the geofencing code that I have, mostly operates for circular region. Can I manipulate the GeofenceTransition value anyway? Is there anything I can do with geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation()?I will post my code references below. If you need any more reference, please do let me know.

Inside HomeActivity, after getting the latitude, longitude value:

```
     double dbl_centr_lat = Double.parseDouble(computeCentroid(alst_location).getLat());
                    double dbl_centr_lng = Double.parseDouble(computeCentroid(alst_location).getLng());
                    createGeofences(dbl_centr_lat,dbl_centr_lng);
                    Double[] dbl_arr = new Double[alst_location.size()];
                    for(int i = 0;i< alst_location.size();i++)
                    {
                        double dbl_var_lat = Double.parseDouble(alst_location.get(i).getLat());
                        double dbl_var_lng = Double.parseDouble(alst_location.get(i).getLng());
                        dbl_arr[i] = distanceBetweenCoordinates(dbl_centr_lat, dbl_centr_lng, dbl_var_lat, dbl_var_lng);
                    }
                    List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(dbl_arr);
                    double dbl_max_radius = Collections.max(list);
                    Log.d("maximumdisHome", Arrays.toString(dbl_arr));
                    Log.d("maximumdisHome", Collections.max(list)+"");

                    PointObject[] points = new PointObject[alst_location.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i< alst_location.size();i++)
                    {
                        PointObject pointObject = new PointObject(Double.parseDouble(alst_location.get(i).getLat()),
                                Double.parseDouble(alst_location.get(i).getLng()));
                        points[i] = pointObject;

                    }
                    PolygonObject polygonObject = new PolygonObject(points);

Log.d("checkinside", checkInside(polygonObject,dbl_centr_lat,dbl_centr_lng)+"");

                    JSONArray Channels =data.getJSONArray("Channels");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Channels.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = Channels.getJSONObject(i);

                        alst_channels.add(obj.getString("ChannelName"));
                    }


                    try{
                        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                                mGoogleApiClient,
                                getGeofencingRequest(),
                                getGeofencePendingIntent()
                        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status) {
                                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.i("geofence", "Saving Geofence");

                                } else {
                                    Log.e("geofence", "Registering geofence failed: " + status.getStatusMessage() +
                                            " : " + status.getStatusCode());
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
                        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
                        Log.e("geofence", "Error");
                    }
```

Now Inside the GeofenceTransitionIntentService.java:

```
    public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitions";
    SharedPreferences shrp_sharedpreferences;

    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        super("GeofenceTransitionsIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent");

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Goefencing Error " + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        Log.i(TAG, "geofenceTransition = " + geofenceTransition + " Enter : " + Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER + "Exit : " + Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL){
            showNotification("Entered", "Entered the Location");
            shrp_sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("shrp_loc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shrp_sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("location", "entered");
            editor.commit();
       }
        else if(geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Showing Notification...");
            showNotification("Exited", "Exited the Location");
            shrp_sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("shrp_loc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shrp_sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("location", "exited");
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            showNotification("Error", "Error");
            Log.e(TAG, "Error ");
        }
    }

    public void showNotification(String text, String bigText) {

        // 1. Create a NotificationManager
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // 3. Create and send a notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.mic)
                .setContentTitle("xxxx")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("anitest",intent.getExtras().get("test")+"");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}


  [1]: http://stefanbangels.blogspot.in/2013/10/geo-fencing-sample-code.html
```